# how to retrive the multipal models record by a single function in django on the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

****** i have a course class ,i make a index function to retrieve all course in template. then each particular course have its subject i make a function course_content and retrieve each course subjects in details.html, i have accomplished the task till here, now i want to get subject-subsections, chapter, topic of that particular subject on the details.html template******

```
             class Institute(models.Model):
                 institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
                 institute_logo = models.FileField(upload_to='pic',null=True, blank=True)
                 institute_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

                 def __str__(self):
                     return self.institute_name

             SEM_NO_CHOICES = (
                              ('1', '1'), 
                              ('2', '2'), 
                              ('3', '3'), 
                              ('4', '4'), 
                              ('5', '5'), 
                              ('6', '6'), 
                              ('7', '7'), 
                              ('8', '8'), 
                              ('9', '9'), 
                              ('10', '10'), 
                              ('11', '11'),     
                              ('12', '12')
                              )


                 COURSE_DURATION_CHOICES =
                              ('sem', 'Semester'), 
                              ('year', 'Year')
                           )

                YEAR_NO_CHOICES = 
                              ('1', '1'), 
                              ('2', '2'), 
                              ('3', '3'), 
                              ('4', '4') 
                              )

                class Course(models.Model):
                    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
                    course_code = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
                    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
                    duration = models.CharField(choices=COURSE_DURATION_CHOICES, max_length = 10, null=True, blank=True, default="")
                    sem_no = models.CharField(choices = SEM_NO_CHOICES, max_length = 10, blank = True, null = True, default="")
                    year_no = models.CharField(choices = YEAR_NO_CHOICES, max_length = 10, blank = True, null = True, default = "")
                    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
                    is_live = models.BooleanField(default=True)

                    def __str__(self):
                        return '%s' %(self.course_name)

                class Branch(models.Model):
                    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
                    branch_code = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
                    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
                    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

                    def __str__(self):
                        return '%s' %(self.branch_name)



               class Subject(models.Model):
                   institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
                   course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
                   branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
                   sem_no = models.CharField(choices = SEM_NO_CHOICES, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, default="")
                   year_no = models.CharField(choices = YEAR_NO_CHOICES, max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, default="")
                   subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
                   subject_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
                   is_live = models.BooleanField(default=True)
                   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
                   content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

                   def __str__(self):
                       return self.subject_name

                   def get_obj_url(self):
                       return '/Subject/%s' %(self.subject_name)

               class Subject_subsections(models.Model):
                   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   subsection_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
                   content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

                   def __str__(self):
                       return self.subsection_name



               class Chapter(models.Model):
                   subject_subsections = models.ForeignKey(Subject_subsections,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
                   content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


                   def __str__(self):
                       return self.chapter_name



               class Topic(models.Model):
                   course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   subject_subsections = models.ForeignKey(Subject_subsections,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   chapter = 
                   models.ForeignKey(Chapter,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank = True, null=True)
                   topic_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
                   content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
                   topic_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'topic_image', null=True, blank=True)
```

**this is function to use the course_content function for models all models**

```
              def index(request):
                  obj = Course.objects.all()
                  return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', {'obj': obj})`enter code here`


              def course_content(request, course_id):
                  course =  Course.objects.get(pk=course_id)
                  return render(request, 'myapp/detail.html', {'course':course})
```

## detail.html

**i want the name of subject name and its sub-sections of that particular course where i mention there name in the code**

```
               <html>
               <head>
               <title>content</title>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
                href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
               </head>
               <body>
               {% block content %}
               <h4 style="padding-top: 10;" ><a href="">Home</a> >> Study Material</h4>
               <div>
               <p style="padding-top: 20;">
               <h2>{{ course.course_name }} Study Material </h2>
               <hr>
               </p>
               </div>
               <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100;">
               <table class="table">
               <thead>
               <tr>
               <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;"><h3>Table of Content</h3></th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               {% for subject in course.subject_set.all %}
               <tr>
               <th scope="row"><ol><a href="#">{{subject.subject_name}}</a></ol></th>

               {% endfor %}

               {% endblock %}
               </tr>
               </tbody>
               </table> 
               </div>   
               <hr>

               <p style="margin-left:50px;  padding-top: 100;">{{ course.content }}</p>

               <div style="padding-top: 200;">
               <table class="table">
               <thead>
               <tr>

               <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;"><h3>*Subject_name*</h3></th>
               </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               <tr>
               <th scope="row" >*subject-subsections*</th>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
               </table> 
               </div>

               </body>
              </html>
```

## urls.py

```
enter code here

              from django.conf.urls import url
              from myapp import views

              app_name = 'myapp'


              urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^course/$', views.index, name ="index"),
                  url(r'^course/(?P<course_id>[0-9]+)/',
```

views.course_content, name="course_content"),
                  ]

Comment: It's not really what your question is, can you edit it and make it clearer what exactly you're asking?

Comment: i have a course class ,i make a  index function to get  all course in template. then each particular course have its subject i make a function course_content and get each course subjects in details.html, i have accomplished the task till here, now i want  to get subject-subsections, chapter, topic of that particular subject on the details.html template .

Comment: So you want when a user choses one of subject, user will be displayed subject related details ? Right?

Comment: yes.. right can u give me any solution.